# General definition of derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Until I know, the most general definition of convergence can be done in the context of topological spaces

**Definition**  Let $f:X→Y$ be a function between two topological spaces. We say that the function $f$ converges to the point $y\in Y$ at the point $x\in X$ if for all neighborhoods $N$ of $y$ in $Y$, there exists a neighborhood $M$ of $x$ in $X$ such that $f(M)⊂N$.

I know there is a definition of differentiability (Fréchet derivative) between Banach spaces, so I have the following question: Is definition of Fréchet differentiability the most general definition of differentiability?

Comment: The most general definition I know of (which generalizes the Frechet derivative) would be the differential $df$ of a $C^1$ map $f:M \rightarrow N$ of $C^1$ manifolds.

Comment: There an algebraic notion - an operator on a ring $D:R\to R,$ with $D(r+s)=Dr+Ds,$ and $D(rs)=sDr-rDs.$ But it isn't more general, it is a completely different view.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you meant to write $D(rs)=sDr\color{red}{+}rDs$, right?

Comment: Yep. @AlannRosas ${}{}{}$

Comment: The title "most general" isn't one you should ever put much faith in. There are concepts of convergence that do not fit the topological space model, for example we can define a sequence of sets $(S_n)$ to converge to the set $L$, if every point $x \in L$ is eventually always in $S_n$ (ie, $\exists N, \forall n > N, x \in S_n$), and every point not in $L$ is eventually always not in $S_n$. This definition does not in general coincide with limits defined by some topology. Similarly, we can generalize the manifold differential to more general structures.